# capturar mensajes warning postgresql desde python - sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

por favor alguien puede orientarme como puedo capturar los mensajes personalizados de nivel WARNING creados en POSTGRES, explico.

actualmente he creado un función que devuelve información de cajageneral, hay un campo calculado en el que si este es menor que cierto valor arroje un mensaje, la porción de código es el siguiente:

```
DECLARE
 fila RECORD;
BEGIN
 FOR fila IN
 (
  SELECT 
   cg.fechaarqueo, cg.slmonedas, cg.slbilletes, cg.slvalesprov, cg.slvalesdefi, cg.cheques, cg.sobrantes, cg.faltantes, cg.rembtransito, cg.responsable::TEXT, cg.fk_codigopuc, (cg.slmonedas + cg.slbilletes + cg.slvalesprov + cg.slvalesdefi + cg.cheques + cg.faltantes + cg.rembtransito) AS monto 
  FROM cajageneral AS cg
 )
 LOOP
   fechaarqueo := fila.fechaarqueo; 
   slmonedas := fila.slmonedas; 
   slbilletes := fila.slbilletes; 
   slvalesprov := fila.slvalesprov; 
   slvalesdefi := fila.slvalesdefi;  
   cheques := fila.cheques; 
   sobrantes := fila.sobrantes;  
   faltantes := fila.faltantes;  
   rembtransito := fila.rembtransito;  
   responsable := fila.responsable; 
   fk_codigopuc := fila.fk_codigopuc; 
   monto := fila.monto;

   IF monto < 3000000 THEN
    RAISE WARNING 'monto no cuadra %',monto;
   END IF;
  RETURN NEXT;
 END LOOP; 
 END;
```

Alguien sabe como puedo capturar este mensaje WARNING desde python o SQLALCHEMY como si fuera una excepción normal desde un try-except? o de que otra forma puedo capturar dicho mensaje?

gracias.

Comment: ¿No sería más simple meter cierta lógica directamente en Python y poder controlarlo desde ahí? Es decir, hacer la query y ya desde Python comprobar si `monto < 3000000` y lanzar la excepción que consideres desde Python...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte Kiko, 

Sí, lo había pensado hacer de esa manera, sé que es más simple, sino que quería dejarle algo de "trabajo pesado" a la BD y simplificar código en python.